# Can "to be more exact" be translated as "um genauer zu sein"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

I would like to use it in this context:

> Ich lebe auf den Philippinen, um genauer zu sein, dem Visayas-Gebiet.

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common expression to further specify a statement is by using ***"und zwar"***. In the given example this would then lead to the following sentence:

> Ich lebe auf den Philippinen, und zwar im Visayas-Gebiet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - `to be more exact` can be translated as `um genauer zu sein`.

*But* in your case, you would rather say:

> Ich lebe auf den Philippinen, um genau(er) zu sein, im Visayas-Gebiet.

The Philippines are islands - you life **on** (auf) them.
But you woudn't say 'Ich lebe **auf** dem Visayas-Gebiet' - rather use '**im** Visayas-Gebiet' (in dem).

Comment: I would actually prefer to have the "um genau zu sein" at the end, as an afterthought. Seems more idiomatic to me.